# Создание кнопки удаления пользователя

Tags: php

Добрый вечер! Подскажите, как реализовать кнопку удаление пользователя из таблицы пользователей. На против каждого пользователя стоит ссылка. А как сам код реализовать вопрос...
man.tpl

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed data-table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>

        <th>Имя Фамилия</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Телефон</th>
        <th>ICQ</th>
        <th>Skype</th>
    <th>Отдел</th>
    <th>Должность</th>
        <th>Статус</th>
        <th>Действия</th>
    </tr>

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
    <tr>
       <td><?=$row['name']; ?> <?=$row['firstname']; ?></td>
       <td><?=$row['email']; ?></td>
       <td><?=$row['tel']; ?></td>
       <td><?=$row['nomericq']; ?></td>
       <td><?=$row['skype']; ?></td>
       <td><?=$row['otdel']; ?></td>
       <td><?=$row['office']; ?></td>
       <td><?=$row['status']; ?></td>
       <td><img src="img/history.png" title="Просмотреть историю заявок">&nbsp;<img src="img/pencil.png" title="Редактировать">&nbsp;<a href="del_user.php ""><img src="img/del.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

del_user.php

```
require_once ('config.php');
$action = $_REQUEST['act'];
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
switch ($action) {
    case 'edit':
        // код редактирования записи
        break;
    case 'delete':
        $query = "DELETE FROM 'test_blog' WHERE 'id_user'='" . $id . "' LIMIT 1";
        $result = $db->query($query);
        if ($result) {
            echo "Запись успешно удалена
                <meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;url=" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "\">";
        } else {
           printf("MySQL Query Error! : %s\n", $db->error);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: @sash, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="del_user.php?id=<?=$row['name']; ?>">
```

Comment: не удаляет.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="del_user.php?act=delete&id=<?=$row['name']; ?>">
```

Comment: спасибо, я уже допер, нашел ошибку свою!